# What is the run time of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am doing a coding [problem:](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-element-in-a-sorted-array/description/)

> Given a sorted array consisting of only integers where every element appears twice except for one element which appears once. Find this single element that appears only once.
>   Note: Your solution should run in O(log n) time and O(1) space.

Just to try this was what I wrote in Java:

```
public static int singleNonDuplicate(int[] nums) {

    int r = nums[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++){
        r = r ^ nums[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

Is the code above run time is `O(n)`? If it is `O(n)` then why did leetcode accepted my solution??

Comment: Yes, it does... And you haven't used the fact that the input is sorted, so perhaps that's your hint for solving the problem under the given constraint of `O(log(n))`.

Comment: yes, the right solution is binary search but why did the website accept my O(n) solution?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have the ability to assert running time requirements, I don't know this website to answer this question...

Comment: @BillyJeans I guess leetcode didn't give your code big enough problems to make it timeout.

Comment: Although your algorithm is O(n), it's a *very efficient* O(n) algorithm.  Remember that asymptotic complexity is not about absolute speed, but rather about how the behavior scales with the size of the input.

Comment: @JohnBollinger One should still be able to distinguish it from an algorithm with logarithmic complexity – if you just throw enough elements at it to get significant results. Right? As you said, it's not about absolute speed after all.

Comment: Yes, @Timo, if one performs precise enough measurements for a wide enough range of input sizes, then one can distinguish between (just) O(n) and O(log n).  But "precise enough" and "wide enough range" depend on the algorithm being tested, and I anyway doubt that leetcode is performing that kind of analysis at all.  My guess would be that they just test one or more inputs that they assume will take too long with an algorithm that is not O(log n).